# "Error spawning child process: No such file or directory" Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

Xcode 5.1 shows that unit test framework I use is deprecated. After migrating to `XCTest` from `SenTestingKit`. I get this message in console:

```
Error spawning child process: No such file or directory
```

I tried to clean `Cmd + K` but it does not help. Xcode restart does not help too.

Anyone encountered such problem?

Comment: Are you trying to run it against a 6.1 simulator? I've found that this doesn't work for me either. If possible run against 7.1 and see if your tests run.

Comment: @EdwardHuynh You are right, it seems iOS6.1 simulator is broken, iOS7.1 works fine. Do you want to write an answer? Do you have workaround for iOS6.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCTest was not supported with iOS 6.x, only iOS7, so any converted test bundles can no longer be run against 6.x simulators.  (It is trying to execute the "xctest" command inside the iPhoneSimulator6.X.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/ directory, and can't find it, because it's only in the 7.0 simulator SDKs -- therefore the "No such file or directory" error message, or "Did not find an executable file at the path" in Xcode 5.0).

Comment: Probably that's right. I think apple can figure out more descriptive error message for that

Comment: Yep.  The Xcode 5.0 error message was much more obvious; it spelled out the path it could not find (which included "xctest").

Answer (score 5):

I got that error too and I solved it by testing on another simulator. I replaced `-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone"` with `-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina (4-inch)"` in my `xcodebuild` arguments and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know about `destination` option in `xcodebuild` and I test it from `Xcode` so it's not an answer for me, but maybe it should help someone. Actually changing of destination in Xcode does not solve the problem, but changing of SDK does. So I think `-sdk` option in `xcodebuild` should help too.

Answer (score 2):

As @EdwardHuynh pointed in comments unit testing in `Xcode` 5.1 does not works only for iphone simulator with `iOS6.1`. It works well for `iOS7.1`. For me it does not matter what version of iOS in unit tests so I accept that answer. If you know fix for `iOS6.1` - post it here and I gladly accept your answer.